# Building a standalone Next.JS bumps into ".next/server/app" ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I am using `"next": "13.0.6"` and building my application bumps into the following error:

```
       > Build error occurred
       [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/apps/api/.next/server/app'] {
         errno: -2,
         code: 'ENOENT',
         syscall: 'lstat',
         path: '/apps/api/.next/server/app'
       }
```

Comment: It may network issue. First check your network connection if it’s ok then check every static and server side genaration page api.

Comment: How could this build on local file system be a "network" issue!?!

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: Don't see this error in `13.2.4`

Comment: I'm glad you're no longer having the issue, but I'm seeing it in 13.4.2 myself :/
I can only get around it by creating the directory just after it clears .next, and before it gets to that point in the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/appDir
I rename `src/app` to `src/application`

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue. We are using NextJS version 13.1.4.

We have removed the experimental block from next.config.js and the issue is solved.

```
module.exports = {
  // experimental: {
  //   appDir: true,
  //   nftTracing: true
  // },
}
```